# Is the relation $R: \{\emptyset\} \leftrightarrow \emptyset$ a function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to establish whether the relation $R: \{\emptyset\} \leftrightarrow \emptyset$ is a function.

Firstly, I know that this can only be the case if $R$ is a subset of $\{\emptyset\} \times \emptyset = \emptyset$, in which case R itself must be the empty set.

My line of reasoning is that, because everything in $\{\emptyset\}$ (i.e. $\emptyset$) gets mapped to nothing, $R$ can't be a function because every input has to have some output. Is this right?

Comment: What’s your definition of function? Is the empty set a function?

Comment: A function is a relation such that every element in the left-hand set gets mapped to precisely one element in the right-hand set.

Comment: Using that definition, you’re correct—the only element of the left-hand set appears in no ordered pairs.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and your argument is exactly the right one.

Comment: @amd You said "using that definition". Is the definition that I'm using not a reasonable one?

Comment: What does "the relation from $R:\{\emptyset\}\leftrightarrow\emptyset$" mean here? This use of $\leftrightarrow$ is not one I'm familiar with. Does $R$ stand for the real numbers or is it the name of your relation? And what does "from" mean in that context?

Comment: It means the relation from the set $\{\emptyset\}$ to $\emptyset$.

Comment: I'm with @HenningMakholm here; your notation and language are unfamiliar to me. Just so we are using the same language: A function **from** the set $X$ **to** the set $Y$ is a specific type of relation **between** the sets $X$ and $Y$. Can you identify $X$ and $Y$ for your question, and tell us what your specific relation is (it should be a subset of $X \times Y$).